# English equivalent of Catalan expression "fer la senyora" for moving heavy furniture

Tags: expressions, translation

There is an expression in Catalan:

> Fer la senyora

Which would be translated as moving it "*like a lady*" defined as the action of moving a heavy piece of furniture (e.g. a wardrobe) that involves lifting from one side, tilting and turning it forward, then letting the lifted side touch the floor and lift it from the other side,  tilt it and turn it again to move to it forward step by step, alternating each side, as if we would be helping the furniture to walk one step at a time. Is there an equivalent to English for that expression?

Answer (score 14):

In English, you *walk* big heavy objects when you move them in this way. From [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/walk)...

> *v. tr. 6:*  To move (a heavy or cumbersome object) in a manner suggestive of walking.

(but you might have to [inch](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inch) it round a tight corner *verb: to move by inches or small degrees*)